# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments - data(as:) - FirebaseFirestoreSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to pull data from my data dictionary that I have made in another file. I'm using Firebase & FirebaseFirestoreSwift modules to pull that data.

The .data() only has one other argument: .data(with:) -- but I'm attempting to use .data(as: )

However it doesn't show it as an option for me and when I try to use it an error pops up

"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

I have tried re-importing the FirebaseFirestoreSwift module multiple times & it is on the latest update.

My code is shown below, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//
//

import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserService {
    
    func fetchUser(withUid uid: String) {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .getDocument { snapshot, _ in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
                
                                      // error line is below
                guard let user = try? snapshot.data(as: User.self) else { return }
                                      // error line is above
                
                print("DEBUG: User data is \(user.username)")
                print("DEBUG: User data is \(user.email)")
            }
    }
}
```

Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

It stems from snapshot.data(as: User.self) - it isn't detecting the (as:) part as within the module

Comment: .data() does not take an argument. https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/e024818c44152adc77573a57d4eed85d11e7edde/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L738-L749

Comment: This is a common issue and it does for some people and doesn't for others - is there a workaround to do the same thing with my code in another way?

Comment: The `snapshot.data()` function does not take any parameters, period. You said: "it isn't detecting the (as:) part as within the module". It is telling you that the `(as:)` part is NOT VALID. If you could somehow get the compiler to accept your code as written, the parameter you are trying to pass would be ignored.

Comment: It's like taking your car to an auto body shop and asking for a paint job, and telling them to paint the car's wings blue. Cars don't have wings, so the "wingColor:blue" parameter makes no sense. Auto body shops don't paint airplanes, so they don't accept a "wing color" as part of the info you provide when you ask for a paint job.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get data and decode it in one step. Try breaking it up.

Comment: Ok - How would I do this using the default data() function

Comment: Did you include the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` module in your podfile? Perhaps it's outdated. Can you include the podfile in the question?

Comment: @DuncanC Your comment is generally correct but in this case Firestore uses the `as:` parameter to cast Firestore data to Swift Codable objects so it's actually valid. It's covered in the [Firestore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestoreswift/api/reference/Extensions/DocumentSnapshot) and there's a great blog about it [Firestore Codable](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/). It's not working in this case because the FirebaseFirestoreSwift is not (correctly) importing. Valid use: `try document.data(as: Book.self)` Just a FYI.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I've already read that blog but still no luck. Any suggestions on correctly importing firestoreswift? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, please see my request in my comment above. - *Can you include the podfile in the question?* - also include your cocoapods version `pod --version`. Also do you use this `import FirebaseFirestore`? When replying to comment, be sure to get that users attention by adding an at sign in front of their name like @Jay

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this issue. I'm still getting the issue in v10.7.0. The error only appears when the file is open in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Just add firestoreswift

```
    import FirebaseFirestore
    import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

    let db = Firestore.firestore() 
    let docRef = db.collection("collection").document("id")
    guard let pojo = try? await docRef.getDocument(as:Pojo.self)
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, I also had a similar problem. However, after I imported the firestoreswift, the problem still exist. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I've just seen this, did you add the framework? I don't know if you are using cocoapod or apple swift packages, but I had to add that, I'm using apple swift packages